# python search file for a list of words

Tags: python, wordsearch

First I started trying to search file for one single word with this code:

```
import re

shakes = open("tt.txt", "r")

for line in shakes:
    if re.match("(.*)(H|h)appy(.*)", line):
        print line,
```

but what if I need to check for multiple words? I was thinking that maybe something like a `for` loop can work, searching the file each time for a different word in the list.

Do you think this can be convenient?

Comment: you certainly don't need a regex if you are looking for words in a file.

Comment: If each line is a single word, just directly create a hash of them, lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just join the word_list with `|` as delimiter. `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier helps to do a case-insensitive match.

```
for line in shakes:
    if re.search(r"(?i)"+'|'.join(word_lst), line):
        print line,
```

**Example:**

```
>>> f = ['hello','foo','bar']
>>> s = '''hello
hai
Foo
Bar'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
        if re.search(r"(?i)"+'|'.join(f), line):
            print(line)


hello
Foo
Bar
```

Without regex:

```
>>> f = ['hello','foo','bar']
>>> s = '''hello
hai
Foo
Bar'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
        if any(i.lower() in line.lower() for i in f):
            print(line)


hello
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: regex is a very inefficient way to check for words in a file

Comment: Since `word_lst` is fixed and does not change for each line of the file, it is better to compile the regular expression just one, before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think using regex here is not pythonic as regex is a bit implicit.
So I'd use loops if speed doesn't matter too much:

```
def find_word(word_list, line):
    for word in word_list:
        if word in line:
            return line

with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    result = [find_word(word_list, line.lower()) for line in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use a `set`.

The code below assumes that all words in your file are separated by spaces and that `word_list` is the list of words to look for.

```
shakes = open("tt.txt", "r")
words = set(word_list)
for line in shakes:
    if words & set(line.split()):
        print line,
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive search, you can convert each string to lowercase:

```
shakes = open("tt.txt", "r")
words = set(w.lower() for w in word_list)
for line in shakes:
    if words & set(line.lower().split()):
        print line,
```

Comment: unfortunately most words are not separated by spaces, I have entire lines that appear like a very long unique word.. but I'm going to try out this too, thanks!

Comment: If the words are separated by another character (or string) `sep`, simply pass it to `split`: `if words & set(line.lower().split(sep)):`